# Would possible to put patterns or it on the skin of a 3D character so that they stay as static backgrounds and not change as they move like "Chowder"

Tags: animation, texturing, image, uv-image-editor, layers

Could anyone please tell me how to make static backgrounds for 3D character skins or shirts like this in Chowder from Cartoon Network? To understand clearly, please, show me your explanation in a picture or a gif.

[image]

Comment: a simple way: use 'camera' or 'window' mapping for your texture, you'll need a 'texture coordinates' node in your texture vector input, instead of uv mapping it... guess if you give more details of your material setup you'll get a better answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a commonly used technique shown in a very simple material:

[image: Using an empty to control texture coordinates]

The technique involves using a separate object, in this case an *empty* to provide the coordinates of the texture.  If you don't move the empty, then the texture stays in place as you move the object:

[image: Example]

Here I have used a *Voronoi* texture node, but you can replace this with any texture node, including an image texture.  To prepare, place an empty at the origin, and set the *Object* field of the *Texture Coordinates* node to that empty.  Use the *Object* output of the *Texture Coordinates* node as the vector of your texture.